# Get FPS of the local video in react-native

Tags: react-native, video, frame-rate, expo-av

I want to extract the FPS value of my video using react-native,
Please suggest the best available solution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

**You can use FFmpeg with low level APIs.**

Here is the Document  :- [FFmpeg Doc](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html)

FFmpeg for react-native (npm)

[npm FFmpeg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ffmpeg)

> And here is command for the extract FPS value from video

```
ffprobe -v 0 -of compact=p=0 -select_streams 0 \ -show_entries stream=r_frame_rate 'The Master (2022).mp4
```

> Result wil be

`r_frame_rate=24000/1001`